# After I connected Setting activity to my Activity2, my App crashes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Because I am still a Newbie in Android Studio, I tried to connect a coding activity to the activity (the one I have the settings button on) with a YouTube-Tutorial. I should have the general settings from the settings activity when I now click the button. But instead of that my app crashes and tell me: Unfortunately, App stopped.

I don't understand what I do wrong and I tried it 3 times. I mean according to the Tutorial it has to be pretty easy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#F4F8C8"
    tools:context=".StartH" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/WelcomeH"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="158dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="157dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="649dp"
        android:background="#B5651E"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome_hunter"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="35sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="143dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:background="#B5651E"
        android:text="@string/new_entry"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="163dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="532dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="btnSettings_onClick"
        android:text="@string/settings" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:onClick="btnRead_onClick"
        android:text="@string/read_settings" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

(Button is on Activity 2 not on main)

Main Activity:

```
    package com.goldenegg.hunterapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private MenuItem item;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        public void btnSettings_onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent=new Intent (this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    }

    public void openHunter() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Hunter.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openFisher() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Fisher.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

According to the tutorial it works already then when i click the button. What did I do wrong?

Thanks for help

here is the logcat

```
03-17 17:47:13.289 2915-2915/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
03-17 17:47:13.290 2915-2915/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
03-17 17:47:13.290 2915-2915/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-17 17:47:13.344 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-17 17:47:13.360 2915-2915/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/Atlas: Validating map...
03-17 17:47:13.449 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-17 17:47:13.449 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
03-17 17:47:13.462 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xb42a4ac0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
03-17 17:47:13.479 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb42a4ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4272c70)
03-17 17:47:13.482 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-17 17:47:13.499 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb42a4ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4272c70)
03-17 17:47:18.656 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb42a4ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4272c70)
03-17 17:47:18.687 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb42a4ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4272c70)
03-17 17:47:18.696 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb42a4ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4272c70)
03-17 17:47:23.891 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb42a4ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4272c70)
03-17 17:47:23.893 2915-2915/com.goldenegg.hunterapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 311 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-17 17:47:23.909 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb42a4ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4272c70)
03-17 17:47:23.947 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb42a4ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4272c70)
03-17 17:47:23.960 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb42a4ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4272c70)
03-17 17:47:25.144 2915-2930/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb42a4ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4272c70)
03-17 17:47:25.209 2915-2915/com.goldenegg.hunterapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-17 17:47:25.209 2915-2915/com.goldenegg.hunterapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.goldenegg.hunterapp, PID: 2915
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method btnSettings_onClick(View) in the activity class com.goldenegg.hunterapp.Hunter for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnSettings'
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: btnSettings_onClick [class android.view.View]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Call your method inside `onCreate` method . Initialize your class/activity inside menifest extends `AppCompatActivity` instead `Activity` .

Comment: can you show a logcat stack trace of the crash that you get?

Comment: I tried to call it inside the onCreate now and added the logcat. It still crashes after I did the change. It even complains about more other stuff now but thats an other topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public void btnSettings_onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent=new Intent (this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This function shouldn't be in `onCreate` body, move it out and try again.

EDIT:

I've done a simple project to show you how it's done. Note that it is important to add your new activity (Settings) in the `AndroidManifest`

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```xml
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
    </application>
```

**MainActivity:**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void btnSettings_onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent=new Intent (this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**SettingsActivity:**

```java
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    }

}
```

To help you learn Android, you should take a look at:

- https://developer.android.com/courses/fundamentals-training/overview-v2
- [Coding in Flow](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_Fh8kvtkVPkeihBs42jGcA)

Comment: I tried it. But I guess I did something reeeeeally bad lol. Now it says Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs would you suggest me to start all over again or you think i can fix it?

Comment: did you add the new log ? Also what's your tutorial ?

Comment: a new log? want me to do a new logcat? it was a youtube tutorial with topic Create Simple App Settings Page Using Preference API. I learned some Java before I started with that. Basics. But because I have nothing who can show me how to do anything with coding, I try to learn all with books and youtube lol I am sorry for being a pain. I try to do all on my own and I hate to ask and show I am too stupid to do it myself lol but its so difficult alone

Comment: I've edited my answer. Take a look and reproduce it

Comment: thank you so much for your help. it still complains the same way. I guess i need to go through and start all over again... idk. Thanks for the links too

Comment: Yeah re-create a project and try this out. If it solves your problem don't forget to check it as answered.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try